# PageViewController makes my PickerView not appear

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have 2 ViewControllers in storyboard, `RootViewController` and `DetailViewController`. In the `DetailViewController` my labels and other stuff goes in.

In the `RootViewController` I have added several ViewControllers to the `UIPageViewController` so I can scroll horizontal.

The problem is when I add a `UIPickerView` to my `RootViewController` and doesn't display when I run the app.

I created Page-Based Application in Xcode to play around with PageViewController. By creating the project, bunch of default codes come in. 
I hope this gives some indication with my issue.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.pickerView = UIPickerView()
    self.pickerView?.delegate = self
    self.pickerView?.hidden = false

    // Configure the page view controller and add it as a child view controller.
    self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
    self.pageViewController!.delegate = self

    let startingViewController: DataViewController = self.modelController.viewControllerAtIndex(0, storyboard: self.storyboard!)!

    let viewControllers = [startingViewController]
    self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: {done in })

    self.pageViewController!.dataSource = self.modelController

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController!.view)

    // Set the page view controller's bounds using an inset rect so that self's view is visible around the edges of the pages.
    var pageViewRect = self.view.bounds.offsetBy(dx: CGFloat(0), dy: CGFloat(45))
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {

        pageViewRect = CGRectInset(pageViewRect, 40.0, 40.0)
    }
    self.pageViewController!.view.frame = pageViewRect

    self.pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using bringSubviewToFront.It may help you

[parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];

In Swift

parentView.bringSubviewToFront(childView)

like:
parentView.bringSubviewToFront(self.pickerView)

Comment: Tried that, but doesnt work. I have added a Button Action on the screen and whenever its tapped it should show the PickerView and when a row is selected the PickerView should disappear.

Comment: How do I get access to parentView? The object doesn't exist in my project.

Comment: self.superview try this

Comment: That doesnt exist. I used self.parentViewController.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.pickerView) but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Add UIPickerView to your controller view and set UIPickerView frame.

```
let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: yourFrame)
pickerView.dataSource = self
pickerView.delegate = self

controller.view.addSubview(pickerView)
```